# Close program in shell script with pkill

Tags: shell, unix, kill-process

I open a browser in a shell script. After opening the browser, I want to close it in my script with

```
pkill browser
```

The problem is commands after opening browser are not executed until I manually close  the browser, so I can't close it in the script. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about run the command that invoke the browser in background (`&`):

```
open_browser &
# wait .. (ex. sleep 10)
pkill browser
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also (it does not always work, depending on how many childs the browser forks) record the PID of the started background browser and not use pkill:

```
browser &
BROWSER_PID=$!
# something
kill "$BROWSER_PID"
```